# Automatically launching PuTTY with vagrant ssh

Tags: putty, vagrant

I run [Vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com/) on Windows and use [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) to connect to my VMs.  This works fine, and I have saved a profile within PuTTY to connect to my VMs.

Sometimes, I run 3 or 4 Vagrant boxes and therefore I have to have multiple PuTTY profiles for the different ports that Vagrant forwards for SSH access.  This requires me to remember the order in which I brought up my VMs.

Is it possible to configure Vagrant so that when I run [`vagrant ssh`](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/cli/ssh.html), it launches PuTTY and automatically connects to the right VM for the path I'm in?

It seems that Vagrant will use the standard SSH client as long as its called `ssh`.  I'm wondering if the parameters that Vagrant uses are known, so I could create a batch file or something which will translate the parameters to something that is usable by PuTTY.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following plugin should do the job:

https://github.com/nickryand/vagrant-multi-putty

Comment: Cool, thanks!  This plugin isn't working for me as PuTTY is unable to load "C.ppk", but this is definitely on the right trail.